# How can i set v-rating to be fixed on vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm Building a page with vue.js and vuetify and i need my v-rating to be fixed on the value that i want, i don't want the user can change that value.
This is what i have until now.

```
  <v-layout align-center justify-center row wrap>
    <v-flex xs12 md4 v-for="(idioma, i) in idiomas":key="i">
      <h3>{{idioma.comp}}:</h3>
      <v-img id="imgCompetencias":src="idioma.imagem"height="100"width="100"></v-img>
      <v-rating v-model="idioma.rating" half-increments></v-rating><br><hr id="divisor"><br>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>

  <script>
   export default {
    data() {
     return {
      idiomas: [
            {
             imagem: require("@/assets/images/imgCompetencias/ingles.png"),
             comp: 'Inglês',
             rating: 4,
            },
            {
             imagem: require("@/assets/images/imgCompetencias/espanhol.png"),
             comp: 'Espanhol',
             rating: 2.5,
            },
          ],
         }
        }
      };
   </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding readonly property.

```
 <v-rating readonly v-model="idioma.rating" half-increments></v-rating>
```

Comment: That worked, Thank you, I must have pass through when I read the v-rating documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `readonly` as attribute.
Read more in the docu:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/ratings

Comment: That worked, Thank you, I must have pass through when I read the v-rating documentation.

Answer (score 2):

juts add `readonly`

```
  <v-rating v-model="idioma.rating" half-increments readonly></v-rating>
```

based on [doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/ratings#ratings)